# How to fix (occasional) empty array? PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a form that works about 90% of the time, but 10% of the time saves a csv file that has the headers, but not the actual data array. I have no idea where to look at this point and haven't been able to replicate the problem on any of my own browsers. I increased the post and file upload sizes on my server (an AWS EC2 instance) and it's much larger than my files.

**HTML header**

```
    <form name="saveData" id="saveData" action="saveFile.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="experimentData" id="experimentData"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="completedTrialsNum" id="completedTrialsNum" value=0>
    </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $("#experimentData").val(JSON.stringify(thisData));
    $("#completedTrialsNum").val(trialNum);
```

```
    $.ajax({ 
        headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Content-Type": "text/csv"}, 
        type: "POST", 
        url: $("#saveData").attr("action"), 
        data: {'data': $("#experimentData").val()}, 

        // if it works OR fails, submit the form
        success: function(){
            document.forms[0].submit();
        },
        error: function(){
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    // set response headers that are required for cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 100000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

    // set variables, either explicitly or post variables from form inputs
    $dataURL = "/var/www/html/data"; 
    $dataDictString = $_POST["experimentData"]; //input as a string version of data dictionary
    $totalTrials = $_POST["completedTrialsNum"];


    // parse incoming data
    $dataDict = json_decode($dataDictString, true); 
    $dataKeys = array_keys($dataDict); //this is an object consisting of all the csv headers

    // format data for csv
    $data = implode(",",$dataKeys).PHP_EOL; 

    for ($trialNum=0; $trialNum < $totalTrials; $trialNum++){ //number of rows
        $row = array(); //initialize new row to be added to final data
        for ($header=0; $header < count($dataKeys); $header++){ //number of headers
            array_push($row, $dataDict[$dataKeys[$header]][$trialNum]); 
        }
        $row = implode(",", $row); //put commas between all values in this row
        $row = $row . PHP_EOL; //add newline at the end of the row
        $data = $data . $row; //add this row to data variable
    }

    // write data to csv
    $fname = "{$dataURL}/{$startDate}_{$startTime}_{$subjID}.csv"; //location and name of file to save
    $fcon = fopen($fname,'w'); //create a writable file at that location with that name
    fwrite($fcon, $data); //write data (formatted for csv) to writable file
    fclose($fcon);

    // reroute on form submit instead of refresh
    header("Location: revealCode.html?code=".$subjID); //any variables to pass to new html should exist after a ? at the end of the re-route url
?>
```

Comment: where is `$totalTrials` set before calling it?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clean it up some to post. It's right after $dataDictString